# Why don't Christianity.SE questions ever show up in the "Hot network Questions" sidebar?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Not once have I seen a question from a religious SE site show up in the "Hot questions" side bar, and I've been keeping an eye out for over a year now.

Is it because the stack exchange network doesn't want to spark controversy by including religious questions? Personally I would love to see a hot question from Christianity.SE pop up every now and then.

The same applies for Mi Yodeya and the Islam and Hinduism SE sites. Why does nothing from there ever show up in the side bar?

Perhaps they are using an automatic algorithm to select the hot questions? In which case I would like to know why this algorithm is discriminating against the religious sites.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What is the reason for the lack of “hot network questions”?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5712/21576)

Comment: [All of my questions that currently have 1k+ views](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/21576/nathaniel?tab=questions) were on the HNQ list for some period of time, and so were several of the ones with less than 1k views.

Comment: [This one of mine](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52897/how-do-various-traditions-define-the-term-sufficient-grace) was in the HNQ list for a brief time, to my shock.

Comment: Also, I actually pretty frequently see Mi Yodeya questions on there.

Comment: [Your question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54805/21576) made it on the list!

Comment: Haha yeah, i love the irony XD

Answer (score 4):

They actually do from time to time – as a matter of fact, here is one right now:

[According to Catholicism, do the saints and martyrs in heaven rise again on judgment day?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54740/according-to-catholicism-do-the-saints-and-martyrs-in-heaven-rise-again-on-judg)

> [image: Image of HNQ]